# MVC Register Routes in .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my website, 
`www.example.com - >` which  routes to home controller by default and executes the Index action.

all I want is `www.example.com/userid ->` should route to the specific user settings page.

when i did this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string userid)
        {
            ViewBag.name = userid;
            return View("userSettingsPage");
        }
```

I thought it will get me to this function, but it gave me an error if it put `www.example.com/userid.`

Please help me!!

Comment: Can you post what error you received?

Comment: i got "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: all i want is if i put www.abc.com it should go to home page. and if i put www.abc.com/userid, it should redirect to me a settings page for that particular user....

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your home page is Home/Index, you can use the following route to allow the parameter to be used:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{userid}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", userid= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This will map to your `public ActionResult Index(string userid)` controller

Answer (score 0):

Define an action named 'userSettingsPage'. And in the Index action do as follows with the desired parameter,

```
 public ActionResult Index(string userid)
        {
            ViewBag.name = userid;
            return RedirectToAction("userSettingsPage")
        }


 public ActionResult userSettingsPage(string userid)
        {
          return View(Your needed parameter if any);
        }
```

Then, the desired page will be called.

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: remove userid parameter from the userSettingPage action. and in the action just type return View(); See if your 'userSettingPage' page opens.